# Add extra columns into test dataset in addition to Features and Labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using `tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset` to convert my CSV data into a dataset that serves Features and Lables nicely for the specified columns from the CSV.

How can I specify extra column(s) from the CSV which I may want to be available during testing of the model, but not to be used for training and for model calculations? For instance, while evaluating testing accuracy, I want to know for which specific rows in the CSV dataset the predictions were wrong. Is there a way to serve an additional parameter that I could leverage to figure out what exactly the model got wrong?

Right now the code looks something like this (based on the Tensorflow example pages):

```
test_dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(
    CSV_file,
    BATCH_TEST_SIZE,
    column_names=column_names,
    select_columns=column_select,
    label_name=label_name,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)\
        .map(pack_features_vector)
```

And then during testing, the code does this:

```
for (x, y) in test_dataset:
    logits = model(x)
    prediction = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)

    print('Act\t{}\nPred\t{}\n\n'.format(y, prediction))
```

Since the generator function only serves `x` and `y` values, how can i say for which row specifically from the original CSV file the predictions may have been wrong?

How could I do something like

```
for (x, y, z) in test_dataset:
print(z[x])
```

where `z` would be that additional column, which I could then examine?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you want to store the incorrect predictions. Do you mean that if you have say 10 feature vectors per data point, you wish to store the incorrectly predicted data points in a new column? Also, what type of ML method are you using? Please explain.

Comment: I don't want to store them. I just want to display them during model testing. I have a simple binary classifier. After the training cycle, the testing cycle loads features and labels from the test dataset, computes predictions, and displays accuracy. I also want to display for WHICH rows out of the ones loaded in that cycle the predictions were wrong. The features themselves don't tell me much (although i suppose I could examine them as an extreme option to guess which rows were problematic)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarifying your question. I believe the answer you are looking for in order to see which rows were predicted incorrectly is by using `model.predict_classes()` in keras. The following code should give you an array of what was guessed by your model:

`predictionArr = model.predict_classes(testData).reshape(-1)`

This will give you an array the length of your test data set that you can compare the ground truths between.

Hope this is helpful and answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Besides, this function throws an error if test dataset is batched (which it is for me). Looks like a keras issue from what I understand based on what's written out there...